# dynamically generated button PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

so i've created some button dynamically with a loop on php
which looks like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $id = $row["DeviceID"];
    $name = $row["Name"];
    $description = $row["Description"];
    $location = $row["Location"];
    $image = $row["image"];
    $dynamicList .= '<div class="section"> 
                         <div class="container"> 
                             <div class="row"> 
                                 <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                     <img src="'.$image.'" class="img-responsive"> 
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                     <h1 class="text-success">The Light is ON</h1> 
                                     <h3>'.$_SESSION['Username'].'s '.$name.' ('.$location.')</h3> 
                                     <p>Light Location: '.$location.'<br>Light Description: '.$description.'<br><br><br><br><br>Intelligent Hours<br><br>Weekdays<br>7:00am - 7:45am&nbsp;<br>5:45pm - 7:30pm<br>8:30pm - 11:30pm<br><br>Weekends<br>TBD&nbsp;</p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                     <button type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                                     <!--<button type="submit" name="button" id="button'.$id.'" value="'.$id.'" class="btn btn-default">Toggle Off</button>-->
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>';
}
```

and when i try to capture it when the user triggers it, it isn't working

i am capturing it like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['login']))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('button with Value = '.$value.'')</script>";
}
```

?>

i have no idea why it isn't catching me clicking on the button.

Your help is greatly appreaciated

Comment: ah i've realised i didn't put the form tag. ill try that and see if it works again

Comment: @A.Wolff atm i dont have any specific "Expected Behaviour" i'm just messing around to get the button to work

Comment: nvm problem solved Thanks Norlihazmey, sorry to have wasted your time